# Prevent an IFrame in a modal to reoald when the modal hides

Tags: javascript, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a modal window with an IFrame like this:

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content animated flipInY">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="closeModal()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modaltitle">Terms of service</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="modaliframe"></iframe>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="modalmainbutton"type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" onclick="$('#modaliframe').contents().find('.clm-act-button').trigger( 'click' );">Somethind here</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" onclick="closeModal2()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue here is that when I hide the modal with the below code the IFrame reloads

```
$('#modal1').modal('hide');
```

I managed to prevent it with the following code:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("modaliframe");

    iframe.contentWindow.location.href = 'about:blank';
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#modal1').modal('hide');
    }, 800);
```

I had to use a timeout because just setting the href and call hide does not work beacuse the iframe takes few seconds to refresh to blank.

Is there a better way to do this without the timeout?